# Use my organization SSO to login onto developer.apple.com

Tags: ios, single-sign-on

Just wondering if it is possible to configure my organization's SSO (SingleSignOn) to login to developer.apple.com . We currently use our organization's email but with a different password to log in to developer.apple.com and this causes a problem where if someone left the organization they will still be able to login to developer.apple.com and that why I was wondering if there is a way to connect via SSO. I have searched the internet but couldn't find anything useful, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Onelogin should make the trick.

https://www.onelogin.com/connector/apple-developer-connection